# Store raw SOAP request as a message header in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

We receive a SOAP message with a `int-ws:inbound-gateway` and we need to store the raw soap message as a message header or similar to be able to register it in a more advanced step of the integration flow.

How we can do it, it's possible to put an interceptor or similar to do it before the raw message is deserialized to JAXB objects?

Comment: Try to look at Header Enricher. It should be possible to take something or all of the raw message and add it to a header.

Comment: But how can I get the raw soap message instead of JAXB objects

Comment: You are probably correct that you need an intercepter. Have have not tried to use one together with a ws gateway but I found this: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/spring-integration-and-web-services.html

Answer (score 0):

You need just to inject an extension of the `DefaultSoapHeaderMapper` and override its `extractUserDefinedHeaders(SoapMessage)`. There you can do whatever you need with that `SoapMessage` and even save it into the custom header.

Comment: But how can I put that info in the Spring integration message. I must use a ThreadLocal or similar?

Comment: Why do you need to do that since after the `DefaultSoapHeaderMapper` you are going to have pretty much everything you want in the headers?